# How to install & setup Node.js , NPM on Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, npm

I am totally new with amazon linux servers and his command lines.

Any one knows, how to install Node.js and it's components.

Answer (score 0):

install the compiler first

yum install gcc-c++ make
install git too to download the source code
yum install git
git clone git://github.com/nodejs/node.git
inside the node directory configure and execute the make 
cd /node
./configure
make 
make install
then Node package Manager
git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
make install